# Combine strings until condition is met in R

Tags: r, string, text, merge, conditional-statements

My data frame is composed by text strings. I want to combine them until reach a condition. Here an example:

```r
my_df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", ";", "c", ";", "d", "e"))

new_df <- data.frame(x = c("ab", "", "c", "", "de"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr::accumulate`

```r
my_df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", ";", "c", ";", "d", "e"))

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

my_df %>% mutate(xy = accumulate(x, ~if(.y != ';') {paste0(.x, .y)} else {''})) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(x == ';')) %>%
  filter(n() ==1 | row_number() != 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(x = xy)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   x    
#>   <chr>
#> 1 "ab" 
#> 2 ""   
#> 3 "c"  
#> 4 ""   
#> 5 "de"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(x == ';')) %>%
  filter(x != ';') %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(row_number() == 1, paste0(x, collapse = ''), '')) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)

#   x    
#  <chr>
#1 "ab" 
#2 ""   
#3 "c"  
#4 "de" 
#5 ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach using string splitting.  First we can split the input on semicolon.  Then, iterate that resulting vector and introduce empty string placeholders.

```r
tmp <- strsplit(paste0(my_df$x, collapse=""), ";")[[1]]
output <- as.vector(sapply(tmp, function(x) c(x, "")))
mynew_df <- data.frame(x=output[-length(output)])
mynew_df

   x
1 ab
2   
3  c
4   
5 de
```

**Data:**

```
my_df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", ";", "c", ";", "d", "e"))
```

Comment: more direct way: `unlist(strsplit(paste(my_df$x, collapse=""), "(?<=\\w\\b)|;", perl=TRUE))` directly gives desired output `[1] "ab" ""   "c"  ""   "de"`

Comment: @Cath Wow that looks great.  I didn't want to use loops, but couldn't think of a nicer way.  I guess the lookarounds resolved that limitation of my answer.

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer, I won't post and, no offense intended, but your loop is rather ugly :-/

Comment: @Cath I'm not an R guru, but I at least found a one-line vectorized way to introduce the empty strings into the result vector, q.v. my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can collapse and than split at `;`:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = str_split(str_c(my_df$x, collapse = ""), ";")[[1]])
```

Or base R:

```
data.frame(x = strsplit(paste(my_df$x, collapse = ""), ";")[[1]])
```